# How to store user data in firefox web extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I want to store data (increasing everytime the extension is "triggered") in a json file to display it for the user. I can't find a solution on how to add a json file where I can store and overwrite data.

Comment: Usually the value is displayed in a normal html-based page. Why do you need JSON?

Answer (score 1):

To store persistent data between between uses, you'll need to use the "storage" API which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage).

Basically, you'll want to include the storage API in your manifest, then call it with methods like `let gettingAllStorageItems = browser.storage.local.get(null);`.  [Here's an example.](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/quicknote)